# How does one get all the documents of a collection in FaunaDB?

Tags: javascript, faunadb

I have tried `q.Match('fooIndex')`, where fooIndex is an index without field, but it returns a weird object which is not a list of documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Match('fooIndex')`  returns a `SetRef`. You would have to `Map`,`Paginate` the result `SetRef` and pass to a `Lambda` to `Get` the documents.

This should do to get 100 documents.

`Map(Paginate(Match('fooIndex'),{size:100}),Lambda("x",Get(Var("x"))))`